# Как сделать кнопку выхода в главное меню telegraf.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot

```
    if (action ==="ufc") {
    try {
        return context.replyWithVideo({
            source: 'ufc1.mp4'
        },
        Markup.inlineKeyboard([                    [
            Markup.button.url("Contact the manager✅", "https://t.me/nwt"),
        ],[Markup.button.url("Связаться с менеджером✅", "https://t.me/nwt")],
        [Markup.button.callback("To main menu", "main")],
    ]),
        context.replyWithHTML('All prices are available on file, contact the manager to purchase'),
        context.replyWithDocument({
            source: 'ufc.xlsx'
        }))
    }
    catch {
        console.error(e)
    }
}
```